# vanishing of Lie algebra cohomology with coefficients in an infinite-dimensional module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, group-cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $G$ be a real semisimple Lie group, $K$ its maximal compact subgroup, $\mathfrak g, \mathfrak k$ the corresponding Lie algebras. Let $V$ be a locally convex, Hausdorff vector space, which is a $G$-module. I would like to have some conditions guaranteeing that the first cohomology $H^1(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak k; V)$ vanishes.

In particular, suppose that I know that $H^1(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak k; W)$ vanishes for every irreducible subquotient W. Does it imply that $H^1(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak k; V)=0$? Note that $V$ is not necessarily admissible, or Frechet (the application I have in mind is when $V$ is the dual of a Frechet space). In which generality does this implication hold?

Comment: I'd add to YCor's inquiry the question about whether you want to work entirely with real Lie algebras or with the complexified ones when studying relative Lie algebra cohomology?

Comment: @YCor You are right of course, I just meant to emphasize G is not necessarily compact. Let's assume G is connected.

Comment: @JimHumphreys I will be glad to learn any statement which is somehow related to my question. Do I understand correctly that the cohomology will get complexified if one replaces the Lie algebras and V by their complexifications?

Comment: What if $W$ doesn't have any irreducible subrepresentations? Like, when it comes from a continuous integral of representations of $G$?

Comment: I doubt that $H^1$ vanishes if it vanishes for every irreducible submodule even if $V$ has finite length. For in Harish-Chandra modules it may happen that the cohomology entirely comes from a subquotient which is not a submodule.

Comment: @YCor In fact, let's assume $G$ is simple.

Comment: @Corbennick Thanks, W should have been an irreducible subquotient.

Comment: @Dima: The formalism of relative Lie algebra cohomology is usable for any field and any pair ($\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{k}$) consisting of a finite dimensional Lie algebra and a subalgebra, along with an arbitrary $\mathfrak{g}$-module $V$.    But it's hard to get substantive results without being far more restrictive about this data.  (See for example the 2000 AMS monograph by Borel & Wallach *Continuous Cohomology, Discrete Subgroups, and Representations of Reductive Groups*.)  As YCor suggests, you should reformulate the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I had a look. I am under the impression that all the results there concern admissible representation. Is that correct?